# How do i detect if an item of a Canvas has focus without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In a Canvas you can set the focus to an specific item by `Canvas.focus(tagOrId)`. But is there a way to detect when it happens?

I already tried `Canvas.tag_bind(tagOrID,'<FocusIn>',callback)` but got the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: requested illegal events; only key, button, motion, enter, leave, and virtual events may be used` which means to me that i just can't use `'<FocusIn>'` here. I also tried to do it indirectly via an virtual Event but as expected that does not work either.

I know that you can get the id of the currently focused item but that would require me to setup an loop which constantly checks this value but i would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're talking about canvas text items gaining focus? Also, are you asking to get notified when it happens, or are you just wanting to know how to find out which item has focus?

Comment: How is your code causing the focus to change? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not just referring to text items rather to rectangles and arcs. And yes i want to get 'notified'. But it doesn't matter anymore because after an hour of thinking about it i now finally understood what an total idiot i am... But thank you for your help.